# JPG conversion issues with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm converting images to jpg and have some issues ad questions about it.

1. I use -c option and tried to specify jpg or jpeg as it's values but, it gives an error, user jpeg2000 instead. Is it the same codec as jpg, if not what is a propper nbame of jpg codec?
2. My files are generating just fine, but their miniatures are missing. They are valid, I can open them without issues, the only thing is that their miniatures are missing. I can still recreate this miniatures with nomacs, so it looks like it was ffmpeg that not created this miniatures, but it's creating them for PNG. Is it possible to create jpg miniatures with ffmpeg?
3. What is the range of values of JPG compression level? I've read it's 1-31 but I'm easily able to specify much higer values (tested up to 310). Is there a strict range of values?

Edit:
I've tried this codecs:

- BMP
- DPX
- GIF
- JPG
- JPG2000
- PCX
- PNG
- PPM
- TGA
- TIFF

The following codecs doesn't generate thumbnails by default:

- DPX
- JPG
- JPG2000
- PCX
- PPM

Comment: Let's get this out of the way first: why are you using ffmpeg for this?

Comment: If you're on Mac, you can convert to jpg by key command, if you set it up in Automator as a service. The functionality is built-in to the OS itself [but the service isn't exposed to the user by default.] ffmpeg is way too much faff for a task as simple as this. There are also a million freeware apps that will do this for you, with a GUI interface & easy parameters.

Comment: @gronostaj I'm writing a program that will provide simple interface for video, audio and image conversion using ffmpeg and a demo frontend for it.

Comment: Honestly, if you're about to code a front-end for this, you really ought to know a great deal more about the back-end first. You're trying to re-invent the wheel, without actually ever having seen a wheel before.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks ;-)
I've realised how complex it is after I started doing it...